# apache log formatting of microseconds as a decimal value in seconds

Tags: apache, logging

I'd like to log format the time taken to serve Apache content in microseconds, given by the log format string `"%D"` as a decimal value in seconds.
For example, the microseconds value `1234567` would be `1.234567`.

Is there a way to do this directly using a the log format string, or would I have to try and push the value through a `SetEnvIf` regular expression somehow?

Comment: Any chance you ever found a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna see the content in seconds, I recommend you should use `%T`
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache's Blackbox module.  See the following O'Reilly link for a guide and tutorial:

[Profiling LAMP applications with Apache's Blackbox logs](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2004/04/22/blackbox_logs.html)

Comment: This does record the time-taken-to-serve information using the formatting string (as detailed in my question) but does not format it as a decimal.

Comment: Doesn't the %T modifier do this? (I'm not able to check on a server at the moment).

Comment: Sadly, the %T modifier just logs the number of seconds as an integer :( So it looks very like I'd have to create a regular expression to pad the microseconds with leading zeros and then take away any zeros left of the decimal point.